# Newton's Binomial Theorem

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, power-series, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

Newton's (Generalized) Binomial Theorem states that if $r\in\mathbb{R}$ then

> $\displaystyle(x+1)^r=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\binom{r}{i}x^i,\quad\mathrm{for}\;x\in[0,1)$.

The series on the right has a radius of convergence of 1. Therefore it converges even if $x\in(-1,0)$. I was wondering what it converges to. Is it still $(x+1)^r$? The proof I know of Newton's Binomial Theorem breaks down if $x\in(-1,0)$.

EDIT: Here is my attempt to proving the formula. I first proved that the radius of convergence of the series is 1 and then I proved that the Maclaurin series of the function $(x+1)^r$ is the series on the right. Lastly, I want to show that the series converges to the function by showing that the remainder of the $i$th Taylor polynomial, in its Lagrange form, tends to zero for $x\in(-1,1)$. This remainder is of the form

> $\displaystyle\frac{r(r-1)\cdots(r-i)}{(i+1)!}(c+1)^{r-i-1}x^{i+1}$,

where $c$ is a number between $x$ and $0$.

The absolute value of this quantity is less then

> $\displaystyle\frac{|r|^{i+1}}{(i+1)!}|c+1|^{r-i-1}|x|^{i+1}$.

The first and third factor in the product on the right tend to zero as $i$ tends to infinity. But in order for the second factor to tend to zero I need $c$ to be nonnegative, which is guaranteed if we restrict $x$ to the interval $[0,1)$.

Is there a way to fix this proof to make it work for $x\in(-1,0)$?

Comment: Yes it converges to $(1+x)^r$ too.  See, e.g., [this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Advanced_Calculus/Newton%27s_general_binomial_theorem) proof.  (Historically, Newton [didn't](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3612767) [prove](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/5015/) his binomial series and was not specific about the nature of the series.  The formal justification was from later mathematicians from Euler to Abel using techniques not available in 17th century.  Hence you find different opinions about whether $x$ can be negative if you do a search online today.)

Comment: @user10354138 is there a way to make my proof work for $x\in(-1,0)$? I edited the question to include my attempt at a proof.

Comment: You made a mistake in your proof claiming the $\lvert r\rvert^{i+1}$ bounds $r(r-1)\dots (r-i)$ -- consider $i\gg\lvert r\rvert$ for noninteger $r$.

Comment: @user10354138 oh damn you are right.

Comment: @user10354138 is there a way of fixing it?

Comment: Yes there is -- you can bound it by polynomial growth.  But Lagrange's form is notoriously bad for binomial and logarithm series.  Better to use [Cauchy or even Schlömilch form](/a/2637499/) or the [integral form](/a/403777/).